# How to reduce load on CPU/GPU while producing multiple squares in ThreeJs?

Tags: three.js

```
function createPlane() {
  for (let i = -77; i < 78; i++) {
    for (let j = -38; j < 39; j++) {
      const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 0.1);
      const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xffff00,
      });
      const plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      plane.position.set(i, j, 0);
      scene.add(plane);
    }
  }
}

createPlane();
```

so I have like 12k boxes to draw on my screen which comprises of a plane all together, but doing so takes like a second or 2 to load and further process I have to do on these boxes(like change their color on touch) lags and some boxes do not change color due to that lag.
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you reuse the geometry and material which should noticeably decrase the execution time of `createPlane()`. Try it like so:

```js
function createPlane() {

  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 0.1);
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xffff00,
  });

  for (let i = -77; i < 78; i++) {
    for (let j = -38; j < 39; j++) {
      const plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      plane.position.set(i, j, 0);
      scene.add(plane);
    }
  }
}

createPlane();
```

Comment: Also check out [`InstancedMesh`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/InstancedMesh) which can help speed up rendering performance so your `renderer.render` calls executes faster.

Comment: Geometry I can do but I need different materials for all cuz I would be modifying individual mesh's materials.

Comment: That's fine. Reusing the geometry should save way more time than creating material objects.